# Get desktop version of a website

Tags: java, android, web

I'm using HTTP connection to scrape "http://www.thecinemas.aw/main/" for data, but when I run it on my phone it goes to the mobile version. Is there anyway I can force it to download the desktop version?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll probably have to set the `User-Agent` of your connection to pretend that it's a desktop client.

If you're using [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), you can do something like:

```
URL url = new URL( "http://www.thecinemas.aw/main/" );
HttpUrlConnection connection = (HttpUrlConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty( "User-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4" );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing the user-agent in the header of your HTTP request.